# Java - Finding The Parameter Of The IN Clause Used To Generate A Partcular Row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am firing a query after fetching it from an XML file. The query has got an IN clause to which I am passing hundreds of parameters fetched from another table. Now I retrieve thousands of records. Want to know if there is a way to figure out the particular IN clause parameter used to retrieve a particular row.

For EXP - Suppose I fire a query 'Select a,b,c from Table where d IN (p,q,r)'

P.S - The above query is a sample query to clear my question, not the query that I am using in my program. The queries I am using are far more complex and fetched dynamically from an XML file as I have already mention.

Now lets say, I get three rows Row1, Row2, Row3. Want to know using which IN parameter (p, q or r) Row1 is generated. So as for Row2 and Row3.

Hope I am clear with my question :)

Comment: how about `select a, b, c, d from table where d in (p, q, r)`?

Comment: Why don't you include `d` in your select?

Comment: Yes I could, but this is just an example to clear my question. In reality I am using very complex queries with many joins and more of I am not sure what the query could be since I am getting it dynamically from an XML file. So the parameters used in IN clause is getting used to get data which are further used in JOIN to other tables and eventually generating an entire set of different data from some other table

Comment: @DJ_NTT . . . I think you should ask another question providing more detail about the query you are fetching and what information you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess for most databases there is no direct way to find it out. However you can emulate it with a `CASE` statement. I think the syntak is vendor depended.

```
Select a,b,c,
  CASE
    WHEN d = p THEN 'p'
    WHEN d = q THEN 'q'
    WHEN d = r THEN 'r'
  END as selcol
from Table where d IN (p,q,r)'
```

Our you could write a function that does the same.

Comment: This option is ruled out, since as a developer I am agnostic about the queries that I will get to process. Thr queries would be handed over during runtime. So modfication of the query is not an option. I am in lookout of a solution which doesn't involve modfication of the query, whatsoever